# How to find `Distinct` records in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I want to find `distinct` records in entity framework. My code is as below

```
var distinctYear = _objCalRepos
    .GetDetails()
    .Select(o => new CalendarList { Mdate = o.Mdate.Year.ToString() })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

ddlYear.DataSource = distinctYear;
ddlYear.DataTextField = "Mdate";
ddlYear.DataValueField = "Mdate";
ddlYear.DataBind();
```

Here Distinct not works. It will return all entries(duplicated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinct is not working, probably because CalendarList is not comparable.
Try this:

```
var distinctYear = _objCalRepos
    .GetDetails()
    .Select(o => o.Mdate.Year.ToString())
    .Distinct()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(o => new CalendarList { Mdate = o }))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy`

```
var distinctYear = _objCalRepos
    .GetDetails()
    .Select(o => new CalendarList { Mdate = o.Mdate.Year.ToString() })
    .GroupBy(cl => cl.Mdate )
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```